# reledmac/reledpar: synchronization of the paragraphs (a single short paragraph on a whole page)

Tags: paragraphs, reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

I am using reledpar and reledmac in my phd thesis to show, on a left page, Latin text and, on the right page, its translation in French. I am using a double apparatus on the left side and notes on the right side.

As I am working on prose texts, the translation is longer than the original text. My problem is that, after the compilation, I often get only a single short paragraph on a whole page, as, for example, on this picture:

[image]

I guess (I can be wrong) that this error might be due to the length of my texts and/or paragraphs and/or footnotes on other pages, which is the reason why I did not change the text here. On some pages, I don't have this problem, but it happens frequently (and considerably increases the number of pages...) I tried to move some footnotes from right to left with \footnoteXnomk / \footnoteXmk, to change \maxhnotesX and \setgoalfraction, but it still occurs and I do not understand why.

I did not see any special pattern in the problematic paragraphs, but the following ones are often longer and/or associated with many notes. Sometimes the following pages contain only one long paragraph, and sometimes they follow each other.

For example, this problem happens with the following text :

```
        \begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}

\beginnumbering
\autopar

\pstart[\section{TITLE}] 

THE BEGINNING OF THE TEXT LOOKS LIKE THAT\footnoteB{Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio. Nulla eleifend ullamcorper mattis. Fusce vel scelerisque dolor. Nunc vulputate est in leo viverra sagittis. Nulla imperdiet at ex in gravida. Nunc dictum sapien ex, sit amet cursus diam porta a. Ut rutrum tempus lacus ut mattis. Mauris nulla sapien, rutrum eu cursus eget, sollicitudin eu mauris.}.\pend

Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio\footnoteA{Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. Maecenas luctus rhoncus felis, eu pellentesque mauris porta ac. Aliquam at volutpat purus. Ut mattis sapien non elit posuere eleifend. Aliquam sed elit ac arcu sagittis pulvinar a non sem\footnoteB{Ut mattis sapien non elit}.

Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio. Nulla eleifend ullamcorper mattis. Fusce vel scelerisque dolor. Nunc vulputate est in leo viverra sagittis. Nulla imperdiet at ex in gravida. Nunc dictum sapien ex, sit amet cursus diam porta a. Ut rutrum tempus lacus ut mattis. Mauris nulla sapien, rutrum eu cursus eget, sollicitudin eu mauris\footnoteB{Proin erat lectus, laoreet in lobortis vitae, maximus non risus. In finibus tortor vitae efficitur auctor. Sed consectetur orci ut scelerisque sagittis. Curabitur nec tellus enim. Nam quis congue nisl, quis hendrerit neque. Sed id egestas tortor, a hendrerit ante. Phasellus tellus libero, feugiat eu congue ac, egestas eu mauris. Aliquam hendrerit ac lectus sit amet lobortis.}.

Proin erat lectus, laoreet in lobortis vitae, maximus non risus. In finibus tortor vitae efficitur auctor. Sed consectetur orci ut scelerisque sagittis. Curabitur nec tellus enim. Nam quis congue nisl, quis hendrerit neque. Sed id egestas tortor, a hendrerit ante\footnoteA{Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio. Nulla eleifend ullamcorper mattis. Fusce vel scelerisque dolor. Nunc vulputate est in leo viverra sagittis. Nulla imperdiet at ex in gravida. Nunc dictum sapien ex, sit amet cursus diam porta a. Ut rutrum tempus lacus ut mattis. Mauris nulla sapien, rutrum eu cursus eget, sollicitudin eu mauris}. Phasellus tellus libero, feugiat eu congue ac, egestas eu mauris. Aliquam hendrerit ac lectus sit amet lobortis.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. Maecenas luctus rhoncus felis, eu pellentesque mauris porta ac\footnoteA{Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio. Nulla eleifend ullamcorper mattis. Fusce vel scelerisque dolor.}. Aliquam at volutpat purus. Ut mattis sapien non elit posuere eleifend. Aliquam sed elit ac arcu sagittis pulvinar a non sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. Maecenas luctus rhoncus felis, eu pellentesque mauris porta ac. Aliquam at volutpat purus. Ut mattis sapien non elit posuere eleifend. Aliquam sed elit ac arcu sagittis pulvinar a non sem\footnoteB{Suspendisse in lorem erat. Donec condimentum lacus at laoreet rutrum. Duis hendrerit finibus enim porttitor suscipit. Proin maximus ligula orci, vel dapibus eros mattis in. Morbi ipsum eros, iaculis vitae aliquet a, semper sed velit. Fusce aliquet ultrices arcu, mattis pretium purus molestie vel.}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. 

\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering
\autopar

\pstart[\section{TITLE}] 

THE BEGINNING OF THE TEXT LOOKS LIKE THAT.\pend

Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio\footnoteC{Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed.}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. Maecenas luctus rhoncus felis, eu pellentesque mauris porta ac. Aliquam at volutpat purus\footnoteC{Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed.}. Ut mattis sapien non elit posuere eleifend. Aliquam sed elit ac arcu sagittis pulvinar a non sem\footnoteC{Suspendisse in lorem erat. Donec condimentum lacus at laoreet rutrum. Duis hendrerit finibus enim porttitor suscipit. Proin maximus ligula orci, vel dapibus eros mattis in. Morbi ipsum eros, iaculis vitae aliquet a, semper sed velit. Fusce aliquet ultrices arcu, mattis pretium purus molestie vel.Suspendisse in lorem erat. Donec condimentum lacus at laoreet rutrum. Duis hendrerit finibus enim porttitor suscipit. Proin maximus ligula orci, vel dapibus eros mattis in. Morbi ipsum eros, iaculis vitae aliquet a, semper sed velit. Fusce aliquet ultrices arcu, mattis pretium purus molestie vel.}.

Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio. Nulla eleifend ullamcorper mattis. Fusce vel scelerisque dolor. Nunc vulputate est in leo viverra sagittis. Nulla imperdiet at ex in gravida. Nunc dictum sapien ex, sit amet cursus diam porta a\footnoteC{Suspendisse quis laoreet ante.}. Ut rutrum tempus lacus ut mattis. Mauris nulla sapien, rutrum eu cursus eget, sollicitudin eu mauris. Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio. Nulla eleifend ullamcorper mattis. Fusce vel scelerisque dolor. Nunc vulputate est in leo viverra sagittis. Nulla imperdiet at ex in gravida. Nunc dictum sapien ex, sit amet cursus diam porta a. Ut rutrum tempus lacus ut mattis. Mauris nulla sapien, rutrum eu cursus eget, sollicitudin eu mauris. Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio. Nulla eleifend ullamcorper mattis. Fusce vel scelerisque dolor. Nunc vulputate est in leo viverra sagittis. Nulla imperdiet at ex in gravida. Nunc dictum sapien ex, sit amet cursus diam porta a. Ut rutrum tempus lacus ut mattis. Mauris nulla sapien, rutrum eu cursus eget, sollicitudin eu mauris\footnoteC{Suspendisse quis laoreet ante. Nulla non mattis odio. Nulla eleifend ullamcorper mattis. Fusce vel scelerisque dolor. Nunc vulputate est in leo viverra sagittis. Nulla imperdiet at ex in gravida. Nunc dictum sapien ex, sit amet cursus diam porta a. Ut rutrum tempus lacus ut mattis. Mauris nulla sapien, rutrum eu cursus eget, sollicitudin eu mauris}.

Proin erat lectus, laoreet in lobortis vitae, maximus non risus. In finibus tortor vitae efficitur auctor. Sed consectetur orci ut scelerisque sagittis. Curabitur nec tellus enim. Nam quis congue nisl, quis hendrerit neque. Sed id egestas tortor, a hendrerit ante. Phasellus tellus libero, feugiat eu congue ac, egestas eu mauris. Aliquam hendrerit ac lectus sit amet lobortis. Integer semper sapien id sollicitudin pulvinar. Nullam enim arcu, posuere at nibh sed, mattis consequat diam. Mauris at justo vel tortor aliquet ullamcorper. Quisque a molestie nibh. Phasellus elementum ante non turpis commodo commodo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce euismod nisl elementum nibh eleifend finibus. Integer sit amet purus at turpis scelerisque mollis id vel tellus. Integer faucibus id eros ac efficitur. Cras in arcu augue. Duis porttitor faucibus sem, lobortis tempus erat semper in. Curabitur semper egestas diam fringilla hendrerit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac\footnoteC{Proin erat lectus, laoreet in lobortis vitae, maximus non risus. In finibus tortor vitae efficitur auctor. Sed consectetur orci ut scelerisque sagittis. Curabitur nec tellus enim. Nam quis congue nisl, quis hendrerit neque. Sed id egestas tortor, a hendrerit ante. Phasellus tellus libero, feugiat eu congue ac, egestas eu mauris. Aliquam hendrerit ac lectus sit amet lobortis.} ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam interdum a velit ut molestie. Phasellus sagittis imperdiet augue, quis interdum risus tristique quis. Suspendisse in lorem erat. Donec condimentum lacus at laoreet rutrum. Duis hendrerit finibus enim porttitor suscipit. Proin maximus ligula orci, vel dapibus eros mattis in. Morbi ipsum eros, iaculis vitae aliquet a, semper sed velit. Fusce aliquet ultrices arcu, mattis pretium purus molestie vel. Suspendisse erat enim, porttitor finibus erat non, dignissim mollis tellus. Pellentesque ut urna cursus, fringilla diam\footnoteC{Phasellus tellus libero, feugiat eu co} non, blandit nunc. Fusce volutpat lacus ac elit blandit tristique. Duis molestie ultricies lacinia\footnoteC{Phasellus sagittis imperdiet augue, quis interdum risus tristique quis. Suspendisse in lorem erat. Donec condimentum lacus at laoreet rutr}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. Maecenas luctus rhoncus felis, eu pellentesque mauris porta ac. Aliquam at volutpat purus. Ut mattis sapien non elit posuere eleifend. Aliquam sed elit ac arcu sagittis pulvinar a non sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. Maecenas luctus rhoncus felis, eu pellentesque mauris porta ac. Aliquam at volutpat purus. Ut mattis sapien non elit posuere eleifend. Aliquam sed elit ac arcu sagittis pulvinar a non sem. Suspendisse in lorem erat. Donec condimentum lacus at laoreet rutrum. Duis hendrerit finibus enim porttitor suscipit. Proin maximus ligula orci, vel dapibus eros mattis in. Morbi ipsum eros, iaculis vitae aliquet a, semper sed velit. Fusce aliquet ultrices arcu, mattis pretium purus molestie vel. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra felis in pulvinar porttitor. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum quam id efficitur. In lobortis est elit, non venenatis enim gravida in. Aenean dignissim mi mauris, nec pharetra enim vestibulum sed. 

\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}

\Pages
```

With this code, the file, called once with \input in my main document, compiles quite correctly – even if I saw in the package documentation (6.2.2) that the setting « advancedshiftedpstarts » implies that every paragraph running on two pages on one side has to run on two pages in the other side. But the thing is that, if I call the file twice, the first one remains the same, but the second one end up like the picture I posted. I really don’t understand why : when I compile four or five texts that way, sometimes I get a PDF, sometimes it doesn’t work, telling me that the left page ended on the right page and putting all the footnotes in the end of a file.

I tried to compile the file called twice with the settings « advancedshiftedpstarts », « shiftedpstarts » , or only with the setting « nomaxlines »: sometimes I got the error « Package reledpar Error: The left page has ended on a right page. », sometimes it worked.

So, I would like to ask

1. if someone could explain me why there is so few text on a whole page
2. if there is a way for me to include more text on the page.
3. why does the compilation sometimes work, sometimes does not.

I hope I have been clear. Thank you a lot if you can help me!

Here is my preamble:

```
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[series={A,B,C},noend,nocritical]{reledmac}
\usepackage[nomaxlines]{reledpar}
\maxhnotesX{0.7\textheight}
\setgoalfraction{0.9} % à remettre à 0.9 après avoir équilibré les notes

\onlysideX[A]{L}
\onlysideX[B]{L}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{reledpar}[2019/11/04 v2.22.4 reledmac extension for parallel texts]

\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[C]{normal}
```

Comment: As you don't provide a real MWE, it is not easy to answer you.

But first, threee questions : 1. Do you do multiple run, using tool like latexmk.
2. Have you looked on the synchronisation option of reledpar ? 3. Is there a pattern for these problem, for example is there something special in the concerned paragraph ?

Comment: Thank you for helping me to explain things correctly ! I edited my question, adding the answer to your second and third questions. To answer your first question, I am not using latexmk. My parameters for quick build, in Texmaker, are the following : "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/xelatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe" %|"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/xelatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You shouldn't use local fonts when reporting such problems. You don't need any font setting at all to produce the problem. Presumably, `polyglossia` isn't needed either and certainly not `biblatex`. Please remove all those code blocks, compile, and see if the issue persists. More generally, please simplify the code you post here: [**minimality**](https://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) is the key to pinpointing where exactly the issue might lie. This helps us help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices. I shortened the preamble, edited the file and added a description of the error I get.